# Rename parameter in a WCF client interface

Tags: .net, wcf, interface, parameters, rename

I was wondering if there is a way to rename a parameter in a WCF client interface method ,just the same way I can rename methods or enumerations:

Renaming methods:

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(Name = "intError")]
        public int ErrorCode {...}
```

Renaming enumerations:

```
public enum MyEnumeration: int {

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        None = 0,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute(Value = "FirstOption")]
        First= 1,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        SecondOption= 2,
    }
```

Renaming parameters??

I want to rename an interface parameter named "error" which FxCop doesn't like. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use [MessageParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.messageparameterattribute.aspx) for renaming parametrs:

```
 void LoadOrder([MessageParameter(Name = "StockCode")]string stockCode,
        [MessageParameter(Name = "OrderCode")]string orderCode);
```